# Cleaning Emails for Custom Email System

Tags: email, parsing, gmail

I have noticed the various email clients prepend/append text to the text written by the user. For example, Gmail seems to prepend the following text to all email bodies:

"On Tue, Jul 14, 2015 at 11:41 AM, Jonny Bravo wrote: >"

The added text differs based on the client. I am not interested in this information. I would like to be able to extract the message body from the text with an approach that is relatively cross-platform. Does anything like this exist? Is the best solution to clean the text on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem at mailparser.io when we developed our "last reply" filter. We get very decent results by just checking against a set of regular expression.

The regular expressions we use are:

```
'/^(--)$/ms', // -- Signature break
'/^(-----(.+))$/ms', // ----- reply above
'/^(From:(.+))$/ms', // From:
'/^(On\s(.+)wrote:)$/ms', // On DATE, NAME <EMAIL> wrote:
'/^(Sent from(.+))$/ms', // Sent from (iPhone / iPad / Windows Mail ...)
```

With those you should actually catch most cases produced by e-mail clients which have their language set to English.

---

Comment: I have started building something similar. Thank you for sharing this with me. This will save me a lot of time :)